# Codeigniter multiple where condition

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a problem i only want to select a specific row/s with user_id = $this->session->id , status = 4 hours, 8 hours and work from home.

EDIT:
all my status is

- Work From Home
- 8 hours
- 4 hours
- Vacation Leave
- Sick Leave

but what happened is it only returns all the Work From Home of the specific user_id and not included the 4 hours and 8 hours status

**Controller**

```
$order_by = "id desc";
$where = ['user_id' => $this->session->id,'status' => '4 hours', 'status' => '8 hours','status' => 'Work From Home'];
$this->Crud_model->fetch('record',$where,"","",$order_by);
```

**MODEL**

```
public function fetch($table,$where="",$limit="",$offset="",$order=""){
    if (!empty($where)) {
        $this->db->where($where);   
    }
    if (!empty($limit)) {
        if (!empty($offset)) {
            $this->db->limit($limit, $offset);
        }else{
            $this->db->limit($limit);   
        }
    }
    if (!empty($order)) {
        $this->db->order_by($order); 
    }

    $query = $this->db->get($table);
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        return $query->result();
    }else{
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

Comment: `$this->Crud_model->fetch('*','record',$where,"","",$order_by); ` change to `$this->Crud_model->fetch('record',$where,"","",$order_by);`

Comment: @VijaySharma sorry i edited my question. i copy paste my wrong code. which is that way. and still wrong. I think its in my $where have a problem but i don't know what it is.

Comment: show a screen from your table record pls - because with this query you should get 0 Rows back imho ;) and which CI Version r u using ?

Comment: @mega6382 i dont have problem with my session id because it gets the right id but the problem is it only getting Work from home status.

Comment: @sintakonte I have plenty of record but here is the some if it link1: https://imgur.com/a/GutAU and link2: https://imgur.com/a/SdzAJ the CI version im using is 3.1.5

Comment: This is because you are passing 2 values for `status` which will not be true, so you have to add `OR` between them.

Comment: @mega6382 how will apply that to my code? in which i will get all the records with id is equal to $this->session->id and status = work from home, 8 hours and 4 hours.

Comment: Check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

**Controller:**

```
$order_by = "id desc";
$where = ['user_id' => $this->session->id];
$where_in = ['name' => 'status', 'values' => ['4 hours', '8 hours', 'Work From Home']];
$this->Crud_model->fetch('record',$where,"","",$order_by, $where_in);
```

**Model:**

```
public function fetch($table,$where="",$limit="",$offset="",$order="", $where_in = false){
    if (!empty($where)) {
        $this->db->where($where);   
    }
    if (!empty($limit)) {
        if (!empty($offset)) {
            $this->db->limit($limit, $offset);
        }else{
            $this->db->limit($limit);   
        }
    }
    if (!empty($order)) {
        $this->db->order_by($order); 
    }

    if($where_in)
    {
        $this->db->where_in($where_in['name'], $where_in['values']);
    }

    $query = $this->db->get($table);
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        return $query->result();
    }else{
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

This uses `where_in` functionality to get all records for those `status` values.

Answer (score -1):

Associate Array method:

```
    $array = array('name' => $name, 'title' => $title, 'status' => $status);

    $this->db->where($array); 

 // Produces: WHERE name = 'Joe' AND title = 'boss' AND status = 'active'
```

Or if you want to do something other than = comparison

```
   $array = array('name !=' => $name, 'id <' => $id, 'date >' => $date);
```

$this->db->where($array);

Comment: It is the same in my $where variable it is associative array. but it happens is that i have to get the record with the status of 8 hours, 4 hours and work from home